# What does "que" signify in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs, coordination, antécédent

As I was reading an article in French I came upon this:

> Il vient du royaume désormais disparu de Danafal, un royaume voisin de Liones, et **qu'il aurait détruit dans un excès de colère**, ce qui serait son « pêché ».¸

I first thought it meant:

> He comes from the now disappeared kingdom of Danafal, a neighboring kingdom of Liones,

But when I came across

> qu'il aurait détruit dans un excès de colère

I was confused, the "que" doesn't seem to be linked to anything. What does this "que" mean? Here's what I thought:

I thought it meant

> That he would have destroyed in a fit of anger, which would be his "sin"

but going back this:

> He comes from the now disappeared kingdom of Danafal, a neighboring kingdom of Liones, that he would have destroyed in a fit of anger, which would be his "sin".

doesn't make much sense.

So what does it mean?

Comment: That use of  conditional in French means apparently or allegedly.  It is an idiomatic use found in formal writing.

Answer (score 3):

*Que* refers to the kingdom of Danafal.

> He comes from the no longer existing kingdom of Danafal, former neighbor of Liones kigdom, that he allegedly destroyed in a fit of anger, which would be his sin.

Comment: Why would "aurait" translate into allegedly?

Comment: I think your translation was rigth except for "that" which should refer to the kingdom. "a neighboring kingdom of Liones, **which** he would have destroyed in a fit of anger,"

Comment: Hmm, I feel (I don't know) that it'd be better if it was "Ce qu'il aurait détruit"

Comment: @MarcoRubenAbuyuanLlanes "Ce que" is used whithout an antecedent in the same sentence, and translates to *what* in English, not *that* or *which*. Here the antecedent of *que* is *le royaume de Danafal*.

Comment: As for the conditional, it's used when stating an information the speaker knows from a rumour, or from deductive reasoning. The indicative is used for verified facts, or something the speaker has witnessed themselves. Hence the translation into *allegedly* which similarly marks the information's provenance as hearsay.

Comment: About allegedly, I believe Spanish would be similar to French here: *dicen que hubiera destruido el reino de Danafal en un arranque de ira*.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas *he allegedly destroyed* doesn't look like a non-restrictive relative clause so either *that* and *which* would be acceptable. I didn't choose *which* to avoid the dubious repetition (the kingdom which he destroyed, which would be his sin).

Comment: Hmm, but now I seem to remember that despite your name, your don't speak Spanish...

Comment: I'm actually filipino :)